# Timestamp for different timezones in php

Tags: php, datetime, time, timezone, unix-timestamp

In the below code i need to get unixtimestamp for 2 Country timezone. The output of the code will give me a date with difference but the timestamp is not differ each other. It remains same. Can anyone possible to give a solution to get different timestamp for different timezones? Thanks in advance.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."<br/>"; //2012-12-18 12:12:12
echo strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time()))."<br/>"; //1355812934

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."<br/>"; //2012-12-18 06:12:12
echo strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time()))."<br/>"; //1355812934
```

Comment: timestamp is continuous, it has nothing to do with timezones and always the same in every place on the planet.

Comment: "Can anyone possible to give a solution to get different timestamp for different timezones?" --- this is a wrong question. What is your **original** task?

Comment: I need to show servertime by using php unixtimestamp with javascript (Not using any ajax request) based on different timezones.

Comment: and why do you need any unix timestamp manipulation for that? Don't confuse presentation and data. The time is the same around the world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get time zone offset in seconds using `date("Z")`. And then calculate as you need.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
echo 'Local time : '.date("r").'<br>'; // local time
echo 'Offset : '.date("Z").'<br>'; // time zone offset from UTC in seconds 
echo 'UTC Time : '.date('r', strtotime(date("r")) + (date("Z")*-1)); echo '<br><br>'; // this is UTC time converted from Local time

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
echo 'Local time : '.date("r").'<br>'; // local time
echo 'Offset : '.date("Z").'<br>'; // time zone offset from UTC in seconds 
echo 'UTC time : '.date('r', strtotime(date("r")) + (date("Z")*-1)); echo '<br><br>'; // this is utc time converted from Local time
```

Output:

```
Local time : Tue, 18 Dec 2012 10:53:07 +0530
Offset : 19800
UTC Time : Tue, 18 Dec 2012 05:23:07 +0530

Local time : Tue, 18 Dec 2012 05:23:07 +0000
Offset : 0
UTC time : Tue, 18 Dec 2012 05:23:07 +0000
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work, I changed your original way to use php `DataTimeZone` class. Give this a try, it should be easy to follow:

```
$dateTimeZoneCalcutta = new DateTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta");
$dateTimeCalcutta = new DateTime("now", $dateTimeZoneCalcutta);
$calcuttaOffset = $dateTimeZoneCalcutta->getOffset($dateTimeCalcutta);
$calcuttaDateTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() + $calcuttaOffset);

echo 'Local Server Time: ' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()) . '<br />';
echo 'Calcutta Time: ' . $calcuttaDateTime . '<br />';
echo 'Calcutta Timestamp: ' . strtotime($calcuttaDateTime)  . '<br />';
echo '<br /><br />';

$dateTimeZoneLondon = new DateTimeZone("Europe/London");
$dateTimeLondon = new DateTime("now", $dateTimeZoneLondon);
$londonOffset = $dateTimeZoneLondon->getOffset($dateTimeLondon);
$londonDateTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() + $londonOffset);

echo 'Local Server Time: ' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()) . '<br />';
echo 'London Time: ' . $londonDateTime . '<br />';
echo 'London Timestamp: ' . strtotime($londonDateTime) . '<br />';
```

Comment: Basically this should need (PHP 5 >= 5.2.0). Thanks for your solution.

Comment: @shyammtp No problem I should've mentioned that in my answer